# How to run breach depression least cost with WhiteBox

Tags: whitebox-tools, depression-filling

I am ultimately trying to run TWI on a 10-m spatial resolution DEM of about 8600 square km. I am using Whitebox through the R plug-in and have also run it through QGIS. The first step is to run breach depression least cost (recommended); however, when I do this, it infills too much of the DEM and small streams are lost. My code is below as well as screen shots of the DEM and the resulting breached file.

Which setting do I need to change for this?
[image: DEM]
[image: Breach_depression_least_cost]

```
wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost(
   dem = "P:/AserLab/Projects/OK_Wetlands/Mega_Raster_10m/AllFIles_DEM_10m.tif",
   output = "P:/AserLab/Projects/OK_Wetlands/09-06-2021_TWI/Fill_single_cell_pits/DEM_breach_depressions_least_cost.tif",
   dist = 100,
   max_cost = NULL,
   min_dist = TRUE,
   flat_increment = NULL,
   fill = TRUE,
   wd = NULL,
   verbose_mode = FALSE,
   compress_rasters = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced similar issues whereby `wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost()` seems to fill in an unexpectedly massive area of a DEM. I have outlined these examples in the WhiteboxTools Google Groups [here](https://groups.google.com/u/0/g/whiteboxtools/c/z9jIbI4Tf-8). In short, I have found in my (small number of) examples that this behaviour occurs when the DEM is the exact same shape as the watershed - I am guessing from the shape and elevation patterns in your image this might be the case? I have also seen unexpected filling when a small portion of neighbouring watersheds are included on the edges of the DEM - neighbours may be filled so as to (incorrectly) drain into the main watershed in the DEM.

I believe the cause of the filling is because by default (and in your code), `wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost()` includes `fill = TRUE` which according to `?wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost`:

> `fill` Optional flag indicating whether to fill any remaining unbreached depressions.

This sounds like it would be helpful, however I'm unsure how to control it in terms of vertical or horizontal fill limits, and I'm not sure which functions it employs to do the filling either. The parameters for this function all seemingly relate to controlling the breaching behaviour, rather than filling.

For your example, I would recommend you override the default, and try `wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost(..., fill = FALSE)`. I expect this will return a DEM which looks more like your original, and hopefully what you are expecting. If you're still not getting the desired results, you may want to explore different values for `dist` when breaching (although a value of `100` cells for a raster with 10 m resolution seems like plenty), or try filling depressions before/after breaching using `wbt_fill_depressions()`.

Additionally, I found a helpful book which has examples of using these `whitebox` functions in R, including filling, breaching, flow accumulation and wetness indicies - Chapters 15 and 16 of [Hydroinformatics at VT](https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/) by JP Gannon. I'm not sure if you're already doing it, but the book recommends using `wbt_fill_single_cell_pits()` before `wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost()`, althought I don't think this is the cause of your over-filling problem.

**UPDATE**

Apparently `fill = TRUE` is only the default in R and Python interfaces; running WhiteboxTools in the command line defaults to `fill = FALSE`, which may be preferred. [See here](https://groups.google.com/g/whiteboxtools/c/z9jIbI4Tf-8/m/q3O6p13aBQAJ).